# Added a product as configurable but is is showing as simple? Can I change it?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, simple-product, save

Using Magento 2. Definitely not an expert but I added a product and selected add configurable, however, once I clicked saved, it was listed as a simple product?

Comment: You also need to specify few options and assign simple products to these options. Otherwise, Magento will convert your configurable to simple

Answer (score 4):

**The product is Configurable only if it has children, otherwise, it is "converted" into a Simple product.**

> vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/TypeTransitionManager/Plugin/Configurable.php

```
public function aroundProcessProduct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\TypeTransitionManager $subject,
    Closure $proceed,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
) {
    $attributes = $this->request->getParam('attributes');
    if (!empty($attributes)) {
        $product->setTypeId(\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE);
        return;
    }
    $proceed($product);
}
```

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save.php

```
....
$product = $this->initializationHelper->initialize(
    $this->productBuilder->build($this->getRequest())
);
$this->productTypeManager->processProduct($product);
....
$product->save();
```

These three sections determine the type of product:

- Attribute Weight
- Section Configurations
- Downloadable Information Section

Magento2 can automatically (when you save the product) change both new and existing types of products, so you can change the following types:

- Simple
- Virtual
- Downloadable
- Configurable

Comment: And because it does like this, you cant assign your simples via import to the configurable product that already exists, because it is not configurable anymore. Thats a bullsh*t